# Constraint CHECK using subquery (NOT IN)

Tags: sql, postgresql, reference, constraints

I have the following tables:

```
| student |

 - studentID(PK)
 - Name
 - ...

| Jobs |

 - JobID(PK)
 - Job_Name
 - ...

| Application |

 - JobID(FK)
 - StudentID(FK)
 - ApplicationID(PK)
 - stage of application
 - stage status
 - accepted (default to No)
```

Is it possible to put a constraint on accepted so that it can only be 'YES' if every other accepted field for that student is 'NO'

I.e. Accepted Boolean

> DEFAULT 'n' CONSTRAINT CHECK ('y'NOT IN (SELECT Accepted FROM Applications
>               WHERE Student.StudentID=StudentID));

... or something to similar effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostgreSQL doesn't allow SELECT statements in CHECK constraints. But you don't need it anyway.

It sounds like you need a partial index. Guessing at data types . . .

```
create table application (
   JobID integer,
   StudentID integer,
   ApplicationID serial primary key,
   Stage varchar(25),
   Stage_status integer,
   Accepted boolean not null default false
);

create unique index on application (StudentID, Accepted)
where Accepted = true;
```

This will allow only one row that has `accepted = true` for each student id. It does *not* require the existence of any rows that have `accepted = false`.

---

You might want to get into the habit of lowercasing identifiers if you're going to be on PostgreSQL for a while.